# Automatically resize iframes with srcdoc attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to display e-mails on a page using iframe elements with the srcdoc attribute.

Currently I'm using this code to resize the iframes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe').each(function(index, el) {
    el.onload = function() {
      el.style.height = el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
  })
});
```

But it doesn't always work. Sometimes the content is resized properly and sometimes not.

I've seen solutions like this https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-automatically-resize-an-iframe-7be6bfbb1214, but as I understand that would require me to inject some js inside the srcdoc content and then listen for the window.onmessage event. I feel like this is a cumbersome solution. Is this the only solution, or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Some of these iframes probably _have_ already finished “loading” their content at this point, so that your attempt to add a load handler _now_, simply comes to late for them. Can probably be worked around, by also checking the `readyState` of the document inside the iframe at this point - if that indicates `complete`, then you should be able to read the correct size right then and there, and don’t need to add the load handler any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using readystate as mentioned by CBroe I was able to get reliable results.

```
$('iframe').each(function(index, el) {
  $(el).ready(function(){
    el.style.height = el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  });
});
```